# How to append data from database inside text area using PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to display data inside text area using PHP and MongoDB. Here is my code:

```
if(st==1){
    var data=$.param({'op':'setField','sid':id});
    $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:"dbcon/DBConnection.php",
            data:data
        }).done(function(msg){
            //console.log('question',msg);
            var qdata=JSON.parse(msg);
            //console.log('question',qdata);
            var get =$("#ques").val();
            if(get==null || get==''){
                alert('Please add no of questions');
            }else{
                var counter = 0;
                if (counter > 0){
                    return;
                }else{
                    counter++;
                    <?php
                       $status=array("status"=>'1');
                       $feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus); 
                     ?>
                    <?php
                         $status=array("status"=>'1');
                        $feeddatascale=$db->kf_scale->find($ustatus);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                      $fid=$_GET['ids'];
                      $data=array();
                      $mongoid=array('feedback_id'=>$fid);
                      $ques=$db->kf_questions->find($mongoid);
                      foreach($ques as $q){
                          $data[]=$q;
                      }
                    ?>
    for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
         $('#container').append('<div><div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;"> <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php echo $data[i] ?></textarea></div><div style="float:left;margin-top:37px;"><div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"><?php foreach($feeddata as $v){?> <input type="radio" name="answer_type'+i+'" id="answer_type0" onClick="selectScale(this.value,'+i+');" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?> <?php }?></div><div style="float:left; margin-top:-10px;display:none;" id="scaleid'+i+'"><select class="form-control" id="nscale'+i+'" name="noofscale'+i+'"><option value="">Select Answer Type</option><?php foreach($feeddatascale as $v){ ?><option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->no_of_scale == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['no_of_scale'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['noofscale']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>'); 
                     }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Here you can check `$data` object is containing some value from database and I need to display this `$data[$i]->questions` like value inside text area which is inside loop.